# Regex for extracting full names from string of names and emails

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

What is the regular expression for extracting the full names from a string like this one?

```
string = "Jim jim@example.com John Doe john@doe.com Dr. Jane Doe jane3@doe.co Jeff H. P. O'Doe jeff.h@doe_doe.fm"
```

I need the result to be:

```
Jim, John Doe, Dr. Jane Doe, Jeff H. P. O'Doe
```

I have figured out a solution if the emails are in brackets, but not in this case where the emails are not in brackets.

This is my progress so far:

```
/\b(?<!@)([a-zA-Z'.]+\s[a-zA-Z'.]+\s[a-zA-Z'.]+(?!@)\b|[a-zA-Z'.]+\s[a-zA-Z'.]+(?!@)\b)/
```

This isn't very good because it only accounts for names that are two or three words long and it still captures the .com or .whatever from the emails.

Comment: Don't use `a-zA-Z` etc because it would break on first encountering names like Al-Fayed or Müller. You seem to have handled Irish names by including `'` but not much else. Even if your userbase will be US-centric it's not good practice. While a lot or people who emigrated in the 40s and 50s did change their surnames to be more English friendly people who migrate there now rarely do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Trick: Splitting vs. Matching**

This is one of those questions that look hard if you try to match the text. The trick is to match the emails, and the adjoining spaces, and to split on that. You can split using this regex:

```
(?i)\s*\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-_]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}\b\s*
```

- In [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/qH8sN2), the colored bits are the split delimiters: they will be excluded.
- The regex is a basic email matching regex (this particular one is from the RegexBuddy library), anchored, with `\s*` added on each end to eat up any extra spaces.

Since you're language-agnostic, in PHP, use it like this:

```
$result = preg_split('/(?i)\s*\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-_]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}\b\s*/im', $str, 0);
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hey there, following up on this, did this answer solve it, or is the question there for you?

Comment: Ah ha...very cool. That did the trick. Thanks so much @zx81 ...I would upvote you if I had the reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

use this regex ;

```
[a-zA-Z.'\s]+(?=\s[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+\s*\K)
```

a small bug is that it will not match the first name. May be you can figure out whats wrong.

demo : http://regex101.com/r/sR9cD2